# Splitting progress bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

At this moment, I have the following progress bar:
[image: ProgressBar1]

Created with the following code:

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="25" 
        aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 25%;">
        Process1
    </div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="25" 
        aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 25%;">
        Process2
    </div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="25" 
        aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 25%;">
        Process3
    </div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="25" 
        aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 25%;">
        Process4
    </div>


</div>
```

What I would want to achieve is to differentiate the different process; If the color is different (like between Process3 and Process4), actually it is clearly differentiated. However, if it is the same color, it gets hard to know what % belongs to one process or another. So I would like to insert a line between them. 
In summary, I would like something *similar* to the following:
[image: Progress bar with lines]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Putting a `border-right` on all `.progress-bar` except for `:last-child` will do the trick:

```
.progress-bar {
    border-right: solid 5px #FFF;
}
.progress-bar:last-child {
    border: none; 
}
```

Gives you this:

[image: Example Screenshot]

#### Example Demo

```css
.progress-bar {
  border-right: solid 5px #FFF;
}
.progress-bar:last-child {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 25%;">
    Process1
  </div>
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 25%;">
    Process2
  </div>
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 25%;">
    Process3
  </div>
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 25%;">
    Process4
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works. 
By the way...I would like a proper solution (probably via css), as I do not always have the same number of process bars and my desire is to automate it.

Comment: Yes my answer also works for variable numbers of process bars. Did you use :last-child as pseudo element? Maybe you want to take a look here: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/l/last-child/

Comment: +1 and @otorrillas, this is a simple way to add a visual gap and it doesn't mess with your percentage widths thanks to the default `box-sizing: border-box` in bootstrap. Place it in your stylesheet and it will apply to all progress bars. [Here is an example of the answer above.](http://www.bootply.com/WDgnZqNer8)

Comment: @Maharkus - Adding a little snippet to your answer, like I have done, will help prevent misunderstandings and provide basic guidance on how to apply your solutions :)

Comment: @misterManSam appreciate that, thanks for your addition, in hindsight my explanation was a bit lackluster :)

Comment: @misterManSam Thanks for the little snippet! It was extremelly helpful.